# Where can I find a good reviewed collection of Twenty Ten child themes?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-twenty-ten

I am looking to extend the functionality and more importantly improve the design with post thumbnails on main page, beautify post metadata, etc.

If you know a good child theme for twenty ten, please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My [VoodooPress](http://voodoopress.com) site is a twentyten child theme. Has some pretty cool functions going on behind the scenes. But pretty much every post on the site is about things to do with a twenty ten child theme. For instance, the things you ask about:

[Working with thumbnails](http://voodoopress.com/2011/04/woking-with-featured-image-in-wordpress/)

[Adding image sizes](http://voodoopress.com/2011/03/add-image-size-in-a-twenty-ten-child-theme/)

etc. Hopefully you can find some help on there!

Answer (score 0):

http://wpweaver.info/themes/weaver/ - this theme has push button customizations for twentyten as well as a bunch of child themes.

Personally one of the nicer twentyten child themes is - http://www.wpbeginner.com/free-wordpress-themes/speaky-a-free-twenty-ten-child-theme-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

This site has a large list of child themes for Twenty Ten http://zeaks.org/category/twenty-ten-child-themes/ There's also a basic child theme with some features built in, layouts, slider, header options etc http://zeaks.org/twentyten-options-theme-1-5-download/

Weaver is also very nice, but it's not a child theme anymore.